# Build type information about attributes into superclass for type hinting

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

So I have a couple classes that share common attributes

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, income):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.income = income

class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

I want to make a superclass for these objects

```
class Animal(object):
    ...
```

So that I can refer to this type in functions and get type hints from my IDE

```
def f(x: Animal):
    x.name<tab>  # I expect to see that this thing is a string type
```

Or have nice static analysis from projects like mypy.

What is the best way for me to write my classes to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the ability of your IDE to interpret type annotations, which is unrelated to the way you wrtie the code (except for the fact that you will have to annotate code then...) ?

Comment: Lets assume it's using something standard like Jedi, or that we're using mypy for static analysis

Answer (score 3):

As of Python 3.6 you can use [variable annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/):

```
class Animal(object):
    name: str
    age: int
    income: int
```

These are not class attributes; they specify the types for *instance* attributes.

From the [specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations):

> Type annotations can also be used to annotate class and instance variables in class bodies and methods. In particular, the value-less notation a: int allows one to annotate instance variables that should be initialized in `__init__` or `__new__`.

Comment: Is there a way to do these with Python-2 compatible syntax, perhaps as comments?

Comment: Not that I'm not entirely behind Python 3, just that I'm still stuck maintaining a Python 2-3 shared codebase.

Comment: I’m not sure; you could try using [type comments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments) with `None` default values. Not very pretty though. Or the same in an `__init__` method after the `self.... =` assignment.